# how to resolve this error.....i am trying to implement custom firebase notification application

Tags: firebase

Error:(29, 44) error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

```
 public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
  private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // Saving reg id to shared preferences
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

    // sending reg id to your server
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using the latest version: `10.0.1`?

Comment: yes.....compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'

Comment: You should use the same version across firebase and play-services libraries.

Comment: means what...tell me in brief pls..

Comment: In your build.grade file, the version you're using for firebase-messaging, firebase-core and the play-services (for example play-services-gcm) all need to use the same version (10.0.1) hth

Comment: yess notification recieved...thanks a lot..!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Gradle file all the versions of google-play-service and firebase should all use the **same version**.

As you are using :

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

You should use :

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'` // and not 9.4.0

So if you are using google-play-services, **please update the version to 10.0.1**.